# how much does a certain quantity of something cost given the amount for a fractional quantity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a very simple Algebra problem. Or maybe it's units cancellation. But I would appreciate some help on how to think this out. Given that I purchased 0.44593073 BTC for $200.00 USD, what was the exchange rate? I.e. how much was 1 BTC going for at that time?

Comment: Divide the one amount by the other?

Comment: Why would you downvote this? If you have time to downvote, you have time to answer.

Comment: @EliRose Why would I encourage such questions by answering them?

Comment: @Normal: Hi! I like your XKCD reference. It seems like we have different philosophies about the purpose of the site. I think it's a good thing to allow any level of question, if it's asked in earnest. You, perhaps, believe there is a minimal standard level of mathematics knowledge that should be required to ask questions? I would be interested in talking about it with you (but maybe on Meta.)

Answer (score 2):

You can treat BTC and USD as variables, and isolate them in the equation.

$$
\begin{aligned}
0.44593073\,\text{BTC} &= 200\,\text{USD}\\
1\,\text{BTC} &= \frac{200}{0.44593073}\,\text{USD}\\
1\,\text{BTC} &\approx 448.5\,\text{USD}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate how many dollars one bitcoin is worth. In other words, you want to characterise the exchange by its dollar-per-bitcoin ratio. Dollar-per-bitcoin is a spelling-out of the unit-of-measurement $\$/BTC$, much the same way miles-per-hour is a spelling-out of $m/h$.

Take a close look at the unit $\$/BTC$.That unit is a fraction that tells us exactly how to calculate the value: you take the amount of dollars, and divide by the number of bitcoin. The answer is the ratio you're after.

There is a general lesson to be learned here, and that is that the unit of some measurement is a big hint to how to use other measurements to calculate it. Don't know the speed of something, but know how many metres it traveled over a certain amount of seconds? Divide one by the other (guess which order), and you have the velocity in metres per second. Wondering how much energy an engine has put into moving a vehicle over a certain distance? Energy is measured in Newton-metres, the unit is $Nm$, and it means that you take the *force* by which the engine pushes the vehicle (measured in Newton), and you multiply by the *distance* (in metres).

Answer (score 0):

By the standard definition of cost, 200/0.445 $\approx $ 448.5 $ \frac{$}{BTC}$